# React Native Dev tools on iOS Phone

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

I am using react-native to build an app. I created a new project yesterday and ran it on my iPone 6s and I could open the developer menu by shaking the device to enable hot reloading.

Today, when I started the app via react-native run-ios and opened the xcodeproject and ran it on my phone, the developer menu had only four options. It did not have the tab for hot reloading.

If I tap the the `Debug JS Remotely` option, I receive the following error

```
WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right IP on `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m` file? Open up `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m` file and try changing `localhost` to the ip of your pc. Shake your device and `Debug JS Remotely`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is the code
`- (void)setUp
{
  if (!_url) {
    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger port = [standardDefaults integerForKey:@"websocket-executor-port"] ?: 8081;
    NSString *host = [[_bridge bundleURL] host];
    if (!host) {
      host = @"localhost";
    }
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%zd/debugger-proxy?role=client", host, port];
    _url = [RCTConvert NSURL:URLString];
  }`

Comment: Can we debug this over gmail or something? Maybe I can send you the project.

Comment: Do you have github account? Is it possible to push your code to a github repository?

Comment: I do, but it's on a private account. Just add me on tarang9211@gmail.com Can explain in more details.

Comment: Before that could you try this please? Go to `your-project/ios/yourProject/AppDelegate.m` and edit this line :
`jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];`

Change `localhost` to your pc's `ip`. And make sure your `iPhone` and `PC` are connected to same network.

Comment: What version of react are you using? This is what my AppDelegate.m looks like:

`NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] setDefaults];
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

where should I make the change?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version this feature was released in, but it is no longer neccessary to edit `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`. Recent versions of react native use xip.io to configure this. **If you are on the same wifi network as the device** you should have no issue using remote debugging. Make sure you're on the same wifi network.